# Trying to split an image into several blocks with QPixmap from the Qt lib. Is there anything I don't understand about the way his copy method works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I would like to arrange the fragments of an image (400px x 400px) in a QGridLayout of 3x3, 4x4 or 5x5 size to represent it completely.
I use a QList from QPixmap to store each of the fragments.
This list is filled with a function in which I enter the QPixmap of the intact image and the desired cut dimensions.

CustomWidget attribut:

```cpp
QList<QPixmap> imgFragments;
```

Method concerned:

```cpp
void CustomWidget::fragmentImage(const QPixmap &pm, int cuttingNumber) {

    int fragmentSize = pm.height() / cuttingNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; ++j) {
            int x0 = i * fragmentSize;
            int y0 = j * fragmentSize;
            int x1 = x0 + fragmentSize;
            int y1 = y0 + fragmentSize;
            imgFragments.push_back(pm.copy(x0, y0, x1, y1));
            qDebug() << x0 << ", " << y0 << ", " << x1 << ", " << y1 << endl; 
        }
    }
}
```

CustomWidget ctor:

```cpp
Widget::Widget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(400, 400);

    QPixmap pm;
    if (!pm.load(":/img"))
        qDebug() << "NULL" << endl;

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;
    setLayout(layout);

    int cuttingNumber = 4;

    fragmentImagePixmap(pm, cuttingNumber);

    int gap = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cuttingNumber; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cuttingNumber; ++j) {
            QLabel* lbl = new QLabel;
            lbl->setPixmap(imgFragmentsPixmap.at(gap + j));
            layout->addWidget(lbl, j, i);
        }
        gap += cuttingNumber;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I encountered problems just by doing my tests by cutting the image in 4x4. The dimensions used in the for loop seem to be good, but when the 16 blocks are displayed, there seems to be repetition of parts of the image. (I expressly leave my debug lines in the code)

If someone could help me, it would be really nice. Thank you in advance for paying attention to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#copy-1) the member function you're using is declared as...

```
QPixmap QPixmap::copy(int x, int y, int width, int height) const
```

So the 3rd and 4th parameters are the width and height respectively -- not the coordinates of the lower right corner as you seem to have assumed.  Change...

```
imgFragments.push_back(pm.copy(x0, y0, x1, y1));
```

to...

```
imgFragments.push_back(pm.copy(x0, y0, fragmentSize, fragmentSize));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The answer is obvious. I should have left that piece of code and come back to it later. Just to reread the doc rather than make assumptions.